# Animately increase the width of UICell

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iphone .I need to animately increase the width of a tableview cell when the user clicks on it and add a textfield into it .Please any one help me

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
[UIView beginAnimation:nil context:nil]; //(dont remember the exact call here)
[UIView setAnimationDuration:seconds];
 //set your cells new width
[UIView commitAnimation];
```

the above code should do the trick

Comment: This is right, however, you can't increase the size of a cell inside a table since the cell will be clipped to the table's bounds.

Comment: Right, i guess youd have to make the t able view wider too